# Is "I can't go on, I'll go on" an idiom or not?

Tags: idioms

What does the following phrase mean?

> I can't go on, I'll go on.

And is it an idiom or not? I've found it in a [Gogol Bordello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gogol_Bordello) song. The text is in *[Forces of Victory](http://www.lyricstime.com/gogol-bordello-forces-of-victory-lyrics.html)*.

Comment: It's a famous line from a Beckett play. Grammatically it is entirely correct and unidiomatic...if you replace the comma with a period. If you keep the comma, your English teacher/newspaper editor would call it a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)

Comment: This happens to be a very familiar expression in my family, spoken usually with a kind of stoic calm. The meaning, as we use it, is that a particular situation may seem unbearable, but that we will bear it by bearing it. The underlying point is that what seems unbearable and what is unbearable are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an idiom but a quotation from the end of the Samuel Beckett novel *[The Unnamable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unnamable_%28novel%29)*.  It suggests a determination to overcome impossibility.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning I take is "I cannot but I must".  It describes an internal conflict or dilemma where the only possible course of action is one which is extremely objectionable or difficult.  There may be a conflict of morals/ethics and duty, fatalism towards the outcome of an important action, or some other conflict.

I've never heard of this particular phrase as an idiom, however.  I would think of "rock and a hard place", "between Scylla and Charybdis" or "irresistible force meeting an immovable object" or as more idiomatic.